# Регулярное выражение для сообщения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Покажите пример, как составить preg_match, чтобы пропускал строку, начинающуюся с большой буквы и заканчивающуюся точкой, знаком `!` или знаком `?`.

```
**Примеры:**
Привет как дела.   - хорошо
Привет как дела!   - хорошо
Привет как дела?   - хорошо
привет как дела.   - плохо
Приветкакдела.     - хорошо
Привет как дела    - плохо
Привет! Как, дала? - хорошо
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
(?-i)^[А-Я].+[.!?]$
```

Возможно, я не учел некоторые подводные камни, но на твоих тестовых примерах, вроде, все корректно отработало.

Comment: Еще `^` и `$` добавить что бы строка только целиком проверялась

Comment: @Mike, поправил, спс.

Comment: @iluxa1810 надо начинать с `(?-i)^[А-Я] `

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, а разве такое поведение не по умолчанию?

Comment: @iluxa1810 я тоже так думал, но эксперимент показал обратное

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, вы не правы.

Comment: Сделал вот так - "/^[A-ZА-ЯЁ].+[A-ZА-ЯЁа-яёa-z0-9.,!?].+[.!?]{10,100}$/us" но не работает как надо... в чем о я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Юрий А почему знаков в конце строки вы определяете минимум 10 ?

Comment: Ну так нужно, минимум 10, ну может быть и больше, от 25 например, это не особо принципиально.

Comment: Mike а почему спрашиваете?

Comment: @Юрий Потому что у вас в вопросе об этом ни слова не сказано, а сказано что заканчивается одним знаком

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\p{Lu}.*[\.!\?]$/mu
```

`/` - разделитель;
`^` - начало строки;
`\p{Lu}` - любая прописная буква;
`.*` - последовательность любых символов, кроме `\n`, длиной от нуля символов;
`[\.!\?]` - одна точка, восклицательный или вопросительный знак;
`$` - конец строки;
`/` - разделитель;
`m` - модификатор включающий соответствие: `^` - начало отдельной строки, `$` - конец отдельной строки;
`u` - модификатор для обработки текста в кодировке UTF-8;

[Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) [Тест](https://regex101.com/r/HuQugu/1)